# Upload a Signed Certificate to Amazon EC2?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to Amazon EC2. I am trying to setup https for my website, I follow the offical instruction from amazon doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

And I get stuck at **Upload the Signed Certificate** step

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name <certificate_object_name> \
    --certificate-body <public_key_certificate_file> --private-key <privatekey.pem> \
    --certificate-chain <certificate_chain_file>
```

As a instruction, I just create a private key (**privatekey.pem**) and A Certificate Signing Request (**csr.pem**), but in the command line they request 4 params

1. certificate_object_name
2. public_key_certificate_file
3. *private-key --> I only have this one*
4. certificate_chain_file

I don't know where to get 3 remain params, please help to shed a light.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You probably found an answer for this already:

certificate_object_name -- This is anything you want as an identifier for the certificate
public_key_certificate_file -- This is the key that your certificate issuer provided you
private-key --> I only have this one -- This is the key that you used to generate the certificate request to the provider ... not the request itself
certificate_chain_file -- This is a bundle certificate also provided by the issuing authority.  It is optional for the upload to AWS.  See this line in the documentation:

"If you are uploading a self-signed certificate and it's not important that browsers implicitly accept the certificate, you can omit the --certificate-chain option and upload just the server certificate and private key"